# Why storage overhead generates waste in C# data types?

Tags: c#, .net

In subtopic **Storage Overhead** (on Chapter) -**C# 5.0 in a Nutshell** book- there is this general note that says:

[image]

Now, I'm wondering why the fields in struct ***A*** generates a waste of space? Or, what is the author's point with the entire note?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: Because it uses 16 bytes to store 9 bytes of data.

Comment: Note that "waste" is in quotes. This alignment is done for a reason, so it's rather subjective whether or not this can really be qualified as waste. Because, we certainly *could* not waste the space here, but then we'd be wasting time fetching unaligned data. This is yet another example of [space/time tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time_tradeoff).

Comment: This question is a lot harder to explain than meets the eye.  Aligning the *long* to 8 doesn't actually make any sense, the 32-bit GC and the jitter can only align the start of the structure to 4.  So there's no guarantee at all that the *long* is actually aligned to 8.  It works the way it does because these are the alignment rules used by native code.  It makes a struct *blittable*, important for interop speed.  The native code rules are heavily affected by early 32-bit processor designs.

Answer (score 9):

Each `byte` field occupies 1 byte, whilst each `long` field occupies 8 bytes. This means that, whilst `b` could be placed anywhere in memory, `l` needs to be placed at an address that is a multiple of 8. It cannot be placed at address `0` since that is already occupied by `b`; thus, it must be placed at the next available multiple of 8, which is `8`, causing the 7 bytes of intervening space to be wasted.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<--b->                                  <------------------l-------------------->
      <--------------waste------------->
```

Comment: You don't explain *why* it "must" be placed on an address that is a multiple of 8. Obviously it is allowed to access (both read and write) any of those 15 bytes individually so there is something else here (and yes, I know what the difference is, but it's your answer).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I assumed that the OP was asking for help with the interpretation of the given quote, not for the technical justifications underlying it. This is not my area of expertise, so feel free to post a separate answer if you feel it should be elaborated.

Answer (score 5):

Just look at the alignment. A Long must be at position 0, 8, 16,...

But if we have first the byte it looks like that:

```
b-------llllllll
```

With b beeing the byte b and l beeing the long l. The - are the "wasted space"
So as you can see the struct uses a whole 16 bytes but only 9 bytes are used thus 7 bytes are wasted

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons for this default for structs:

1) Performance, as others have already explained. Placing the field members at multiples of their size allows faster transfers.

2) To be the same as the default for most C/C++ compilers. This makes interop with C/C++ (including all the Windows API) a bit easier.

Note that if you don't need to marshal your structures, you can use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
struct A
{
    byte b;
    long l;
}
```

With that, the following code

```
unsafe
{
    Console.WriteLine(sizeof(A));
}
```

prints `12`, which indicates better packing.

If you use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]` you can get the size down to `9`.

Answer (score 2):

They are generally aligned at processor word boundaries, so that retrieving them is a simple one-cycle operation.  Otherwise, the CLR would have to pick up the whole address, and XOR/shift the struct field to reference it.