# Storage over heading and wasting space for value types in C# and CLR

Tags: c#, clr

i am just second year computer scientist student who is trying to learn more. i was reading a c# book:"c# in a nutshell" and i encountered this paragraph regarding storage over heading in c#.

> Value-type instances occupy precisely the memory required to store their fields. In
>   this example, Point takes eight bytes of memory:
>
> > struct Point
> >     {
> >     int x; // 4 bytes
> >     int y; // 4 bytes
> >     }
>
> Technically, the CLR positions fields within the type at an
>   address that’s a multiple of the fields’ size (up to a maximum
>   of eight bytes). Thus, the following actually consumes 16 bytes
>   of memory (with the seven bytes following the first field “wasted”):
>   struct A { byte b; long l; }
>   You can override this behavior with the StructLayout
>   attribute

my first question is: why only 16 bytes?why not 8 or 32 or other number which are multiple of 8

my second question is: why is it wasted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42439111/17034

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the size of struct A is not equal size of struct B with same fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438397/why-the-size-of-struct-a-is-not-equal-size-of-struct-b-with-same-fields)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504491/why-storage-overhead-generates-waste-in-c-sharp-data-types (2013 year)

Answer (score 2):

Computer architectures determine the minimum addressable space as a "word".  So for example, on a 32-bit architecture the word is 32-bits or 4 bytes.  And it is twice that for a 64-bit architecture.  The processor operations work on words, not bytes.

So, imagine `struct MyStruct {byte a; long b;}` on 32-bit architecture, this takes 3 words (12 bytes).  And on a 64-bit architecture, this takes 16-bytes.

```
// 8-bit word size (3 1-byte words or 3 bytes) - this is the most compact it can be, but we don't use 8-bit processors.
|1|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
|a|b|b|b|b|b|b|b|b|

// 32-bit word size (3 4-byte words or 12 bytes)
|1234|1234|1234|
|a---|bbbb bbbb|

// 64-bit word size (2 8-byte words or 16-bytes)
|12345678|12345678|
|a-------|bbbbbbbb|
```

Comment: +1 but it would probably be somewhat more accurate to say that while the processor *can* operate on data of non-word widths, there might be a performance penalty when accessing data that is not word-aligned in memory.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, `int` is an alias for `System.Int32` which is a 32-bit signed integer, which is 4 bytes.

When aligning to machine-word boundary, it is often more efficient for a processor to access memory at 64-bit boundaries, so the compiler might align members of the structure with that in mind, and actually leave empty space in the physical structure to make it faster to access them.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Does that always work like that?For example, when it works with long(64 bits), is it going to allocate 128 bits inside the memory?

Comment: No.  Alignment is per machine.  On a 32-bit processor, it would favor alignment on 32-bit boundaries.  In the future, on a 128-bit processor, it might align to 128 bit bounaries.  It is up to the compiler.  You can use can force the `packing' when doing interop, since other systems may require a specific alignment.  Normally, you completely ignore it and don't worry about the magic that the compiler does.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> struct A { byte b; long l; }
> ```

The memory layout of the above `struct` might look something like the following:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   a   b   c   d   e   f
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| b |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

`byte b` is placed at the beginning of the struct (starting index 0). It occupies one byte, so the next field will have a starting index of 1 (or greater). `long l` will occupy 8 bytes, therefore it will have to start at an index that is a multiple of 8. The runtime will try to place the field at the next possible index, in order to make the struct any larger than it needs to be. That's why it'll be placed at starting offset 8.

The bytes 1 through 7 will thus end up unoccupied by any field of `struct A`. They are not used by any field of `A`, and since .NET objects do not overlay one another in memory, nothing is going to make use, or access, these 7 bytes. They are reserved exclusively for an instance of `A`, but not for anything, so their space is effectively wasted.